# Get Total number of frames and FPS faster than with OpenCV library in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, video, ffmpeg

I need to check which video can be analyzed and which cannot given the total number of frames in a video and the fps of the video. I created a c++ program to do the checking. Analyzing each video is not an option since analyzing is time consuming.

I used the OpenCV library for starters:

```
    cv::VideoCapture vid_to_analyze;
    vid_to_analyze.open( me_vid.vid_path.string() );
    me_vid.total_frames= static_cast<int>(vid_to_analyze.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT));
    me_vid.fps=vid_to_analyze.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);

    if (!vid_to_analyze.isOpened())
    {
        std::cout << "Skipping vid: "<< me_vid.vid_path.string()<<", couldn't open it" << std::endl;
    }
    if (me_vid.fps != me_vid.fps || me_vid.fps <= 0)
    {
        std::cout << "For video " << me_vid.vid_path.string() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "FPS of the video file cannot be determined, assuming 30"<< std::endl;
        me_vid.fps = 30;
    }

    vid_to_analyze.release();
```

However when debugging it becomes painfully slow  (the program is faster running without the debugger attached but still very slow given the number of videos it needs to cover). I think that has something to do with 4 threads being created and deleted each time a video is opened (released).

**How to get total number of frames and fps in a faster manner** ( without actually creating 4 threads!!) if i am not interested in actually grabbing frames from the video just the number of frames and fps.

Is there a way to use ffmpeg library from c++, would that be faster and where to start?

EDIT: Valgrind seems to agree since (Ir=)91.66% of time spend in the `vid_to_analyze.open` phase

Comment: The data you seek is in a video file in some form or another.  I don't see how you can get attributes of a video without opening the file. (Unless there is an associated attributes file.)

Comment: You are absolutely right, i fixed the title. The priority isn't as much not to open the file (read) as much as to do that efficiently . File must be opened in some way or another so that the parameters could be read. Thank you for correcting me

Comment: Which file formats?

Comment: .avi , .webm But i don't know which codecs (i think multiple) but i can check.
But most important is .avi

Answer (score 0):

The attributes of a video are known as *metadata*.

You can optimize the fetching of metadata by restricting the video file formats.

I/O is where your time will be spent.  Much of the I/O time is beyond your program's control (left to the OS and other devices).

Here are some suggestions for quickly obtaining the number of frames:
1. Allocate memory for the metadata of your file format.
2. Block read the metadata from the file into your memory.
3. Fetch the number of frames from the metadata section.
This is provided that your video format has precalculated the number of frames.

Otherwise, do your best at keeping the I/O streaming:
1. Read in video data, multiple frames if possible.
2. Count the number of frames in the buffer.
3. Repeat #1.

You could perform *double-buffering* and threads to speed things up:
1. A "reading" thread reads data into a buffer.
   After the buffer is full, it reads into another buffer.

2. A "processing" thread processes the data in a buffer.
   The processing thread may want to wait until there is a buffer available.

The objective is to supply enough buffers so that the "reading" thread doesn't stop.  The "processing" thread will do the frame counting while the "reading" thread is reading.  (There is plenty of time for processing while waiting for I/O operations to complete.)

Also, look into "memory mapped files".  This is a concept where the OS treats a file as memory, loading blocks of the file into memory as necessary.